# Ecto.Changeset if profile_img_url is not set use gravatar

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

When a new user registers, I would like to give him an gravatar profile image by default, afterwards he should be able to set it manually, so the changeset method should only apply if profile_img_url is nil

```
def changeset(model, params \\ :empty) do
  model
  |> cast(...)
  ...
  |> get_gravatar
end

defp get_gravatar(current_changeset) do
  case current_changeset do
    %Ecto.Changeset{valid?: true, *is_nil:* :profile_img_url} ->
         put_change(current_changeset, :profile_img_url, get_somehow_the_gravatar_img(current_changeset))
    _ -> current_changeset
  end
end
```

So basically, the question is, is this the right way to do it, and is there an Ecto mehtod to check if the value is nil or not. (Not only in the changeset, but also in the db)

Comment: are you saying that when a new user registers, if he has not provided a profile image apply a gravatar?

Comment: Have you considered creating a function in a view for that? The function would check if avatar is present and if it is, it would render the avatar image, if it's not, it would render the gravatar.

Comment: @coderVishal yes exactly, when no img provided, generate a gravatar

Comment: @JustMichael, well if I can apply the image once to the model, I don't need to check anymore.. does it make sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my current understanding your implementation is current, you could use an alternative style of  code

```
  def get_gravatar changeset do
    if changeset.valid? && !(get_field(changeset, :profile_img_url) |> is_nil ) do
      put_change(changeset, :profile_img_url, get_gravatar_image)
    else
      changeset
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 2):

Found a solution, but I'll not mark it as accepted, to let other people make a better suggestion.

```
  defp get_gravatar(current_changeset) do
    case current_changeset do
      %Ecto.Changeset{valid?: true, model: %{profile_img_url: nil, email: email}} ->
        put_change(current_changeset, :profile_img_url, to_string(Gravatar.new(email)) <> "?d=identicon")

      _ -> current_changeset
    end
  end
```